# How to create regional map tiles for Leaflet

Tags: qgis, leaflet, javascript, tiles

I would like to create the map tiles in leaflet, which will be used in regional scale. I mean, that once I provide sth like this:

```
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar', attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'}).addTo(map);
```

I will receive the tile map i.e for 1 or 2 cities covered instead of a whole world (non covered areas will remain as per tilelayer underneath).

I found a few possible solutions:

1. QGIS Qtiles - https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_basemaps_with_qtiles.html
2. Slippy Map
3. OpenMaptiles (with Python)

I am quite new in this issue. So far I found a few solutions mentioned here:

[How can I convert an image into map tiles for leafletJS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285483/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-map-tiles-for-leafletjs)
that led me to the:
[How to handle a geotiff map together with points with OpenLayers (or other libraries)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/how-to-handle-a-geotiff-map-together-with-points-with-openlayers-or-other-libra/29998#29998)

[Generating Tiles with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14087/generating-tiles-with-qgis)

https://leafletjs.com/plugins#non-map-base-layers

https://support.maptiler.com/i25-use-maps-interactively-with-javascript

Is there some quick solution to grasp it?

Comment: Have a look at maptiler: https://www.maptiler.com/desktop/